# JSON HTTP API in Android app

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I'm creating an Android app that connects to a json api and shows results in a simple ListView. I have found this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) and already copied their code to start modifying it. But I'm getting two errors in MainActivity (see comments in code).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_implement_api);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener /**<-underlined in red**/() {

        @Override /**<-underlined in red**/
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

I'm looking on it and digging through web to find answer what is it causing about a week, but with no luck.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //do what you are doing onItemClick

        }
});
```